# AIX Korn Shell - compare date in yyyyMM format

Tags: date, if-statement, compare, ksh, aix

I'm searching for compare two date in AIX.
This is the first date in yyyyMM format:

```
three_months_ago=$(( $(date +%Y%m) - 3))
```

And I get the second date from filesystem with concatenation of folder name:

```
for dir in /p22_satos/satos/data/*                                                     
do                                                                                 
 echo ${dir}  
 year=$(basename ${dir})
 if [[ $dir = "/p22_satos/satos/data/static" ]];
then
    print "Static dir should not be deleted"
else
    for   subdir in ${dir}/*
     do
       echo ${subdir}
       month=$(basename ${subdir})
       if [ $month -ge 10 ];
       then
         echo ${year}${month}
         echo $three_months_ago
         if [ ${year}${month} -ge $three_months_ago ];
         then            
           echo "The directory should not be deleted"
         else
            echo "The directory should be deleted"
         fi
       else 

        echo ${year}"0"${month}
        echo $three_months_ago
        if [ ${year}"0"${month} -ge $three_months_ago ];
         then            
           echo "The directory should not be deleted"
         else
            echo "The directory should be deleted"
         fi
       fi

       #rm -f $subdir
     done
fi
```

The value for $three_months_ago is 202103.
I've folder 2020 with subfolder 12, so the cycle make 202012 date dynamically.
Why ${year}${month} and ${year}"0"${month} are always greater than $three_months_ago and the if [ ${year}${month} -ge $three_months_ago ] fails?

Comment: I don't really understand your program, but I could offer a Perl script that calculates the date three months ago: https://github.com/lzsiga/pldate Usage: `pldate sub-months 3`

Comment: My program do a for cycle for check subfolder name from root /p22_satos/satos/data/  and delete the folders for months and years older than three months. We have a folder called 2020 with a subfolder inside for each month of the year in numeric format (1,2,3, etc ..), then we have another folder called 2021, 2019, etc... The cycle when it scrolls through the folders concatenates the name of the folder relating to the year and that relating to the month, for example 202012 and we would like to compare it with the date relating to three months ago in yyyyMM format.

Comment: You can use the beforementioned script this way: `pldate today sub-months 3 printf '%Y%m'`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
three_months_ago=$(date --date=@$(( $(date +%s) - (3 * 30 * 24 * 3600) )) +%Y%m)
```

`date +%s`: give the current date in seconds since 01/01/1970

`3 * 30 * 24 * 3600`: number of seconds during 90 days

`date --date=@<seconds>`: calculate date from a number of seconds since 01/01/1970

`+%Y%m`: output format